# How to use list to record path from A to B?

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

If I have a map with nodes 1,2,...,n, I want to know if I can go from `n1` to `n2`, I can use the following code:

```
path(1,2).
path(3,5).
.....

get_to(A,B) :- path(A,B).
get_to(A,B) :- path(A,C),get_to(C,B).
```

But how can record the path from `A` to `B` and show it ?

Answer (score 1):

First, let us get terminology right: The direct connections between nodes (often called [vertices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_%28graph_theory%29)) are called edges. And the whole way is called a path. Here is a first attempt:

```
path(A,B,[A,B]) :- edge(A,B).
path(A,C,[A,B|Vs]) :- edge(A,B), path(B,C,[B|Vs]).
```

Note that the list can now be used to determine all paths of a fixed length.

```
?-length(P, 10), path(A,B, P).
```

Or even all paths, sorted by length:

```
?- length(P, N), path(A,B, P).
```

The price for this generality is that this last query does not terminate. There are ways to fix this, but they are not straight-forward.

Answer (score 0):

Well you could use an accumulator:

```
get_to(A,B,L) :-
    get_to(A,B,[A],L).

get_to(A,B,L,L2) :-
    path(A,B),
    append(L,[B],L2).
get_to(A,B,L,L3) :-
    path(A,C),
    append(L,[C],L2),
    get_to(C,B,L2,L3).
```

Where `L` is an array storing the nodes in the path.

In case the graph looks like:

```
path(1,2).
path(1,3).
path(3,4).
path(4,6).
path(6,5).
path(5,7).
```

This will result in:

```
?- get_to(1,7,L).
L = [1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7]
```

A problem with this approach is however that the `append` operation takes linear time resulting in a significant overhead. You can however try to construct the path in reverse...

```
get_to(A,B,L) :-
    get_to(A,B,[B],L).

get_to(A,B,L,[A|L]) :-
    path(A,B).
get_to(A,B,L,L2) :-
    path(C,B),
    get_to(A,C,[C|L],L2).
```

resulting - evidently - in the same path, but much faster...

```
?- get_to(1,7,L).
L = [1, 3, 4, 6, 5, 7] .
```

Comment: May I ask a simple question ?


get_to(1,3,[1],[2,3]).

get_to(1,3,L) :- get_to(1,3,[1],[2,3]).

? get_to(1,3,L).

Why can't this print L ?

Comment: Well you only declare `get_to/4` (with four arguments). Then you call `get_to/3` with three arguments. If `L` remains uninstantiated it isn't printed...

Comment: Sory,My silly question is your first clause get_to(A,B,L) :- get_to(A,B,[A],L). Is L = [A] + L    ? Otherwise, Where to add [1] to L

Comment: Well you don't really "add" something to a variable, since a variable in prolog can only be assigned a value once. The code uses two predicates: `get_to/3` (with 3 arguments) and `get_to/4` (four arguments). The first clause only "binds" `get_to/3` with `get_to/4`. And this is done by starting the "construction" of the path with `[A]`. The last argument of `get_to/4` is the final path. And this is binded with `L`...